# Xcode (4.3.2) problems with openCV (2.3.1) installed from port

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, osx-lion, macports

I have a problem using openCV 2.3.1 installed from mac ports. For installation and configuration of the xcode project I used [this post from Salem's blog](http://salemsayed.me/?p=240). The example code shown in the post works great. But if I change the mail.cpp file to just show an image it fails. 
Here is my example code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("Lena.jpg");
    cv::namedWindow("Image");
    cv::imshow("Image", img);
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Now I am a bit confused since I'm also not that familiar with c++.

Any advice?

Comment: After `cv::imshow("Image", img);` add a call to `cvWaitKey(0);`. DEbug this application to discover which code statement produces this error and then report back to us.

Comment: I added `cv::waitKey(0);` after the call to `imshow(...)` and debugged the application. The error gets produced by the call to `imshow(...)`. I hope that helps in any way ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a chance that the crash is being caused by `imread()` failing to locate the image on the disk:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("Lena.jpg");
if (!img.data)
{
     // print error and abort execution
}
```

and you'll never know unless you start to code safely.

Comment: This sort of problem happens when you run the app from within the IDE. Visual Studio folks do this mistake all the time, because they put the image inside the same directory as the executable, but the IDE looks for the image inside the same folder where the source files are being stored.

Comment: Ok thank you very much it works! I'm a complete idiot :-) I was so into trying out that if forgot to check for that eventuality! I had the image in the same folder as the source file but the IDE didn't find it.